# im getting an error when trying to launch eclipse "Version 1.8.0_261 of the JVM is not suitable for this product."

Tags: eclipse

The error is
"Version 1.8.0_261 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. Version 11 or greater is required"

But I already have JDK 15 installed.

Comment: which operating system are you using?

Answer (score 3):

You may have JDK 15 installed, but Eclipse doesn't search the disk for the VM it wants to use, you have to tell it which VM to use.

To resolve this, first note the absolute path where you installed JDK 15.

Find where you installed Eclipse, and edit the file "/eclipse/eclipse.ini".  Look for a line that begins with "-vm ".  If you find that, the next line will be the path to the "bin" directory in a JDK distribution.  Change that path to reflect the JDK 15 distribution.

If you do not find a "-vm " line, then instead look for the "-vmargs " line.  Now insert before that line a "-vm " line, followed by a line with the absolute path to the "bin" directory of the JDK 15 distribution.

Restart Eclipse.

Comment: append /javaw.exe with bin directory.